# process a file remotely using ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote-access

I have this `report.tex` file which I convert to pdf as follows:

```
latex report.tex
dvips report.dvi -o report.ps
ps2pdfwr report.ps report.pdf
```

These commands are placed in a file called `linux_build`

This works great. However, this works on my Linux machine and most of my work I do on my Mac

I checked out [MacTex](https://tug.org/mactex/) which is enormous (> 4GB) so I decided to process the latex file remotely (so working on my Mac, and building on my Linux computer). Like this:

```
ssh latex@192.168.2.8 "cd build && ./linux_build" < report.tex
scp latex@192.168.2.8:build/report.pdf .
```

All this works, except for one thing:

```
latex report.tex
```

That command simply looks on disk, not for some input stream/pipe of whatever. It is at this point I'm not sure anymore how to fix this. Any suggestions ?

Comment: If `latex` supports reading from standard input then you can do it that way. Possible just `latex` or maybe `latex -` or possibly `latex /dev/stdin` to fake it as a local file. If that doesn't work then you need to transfer the file over first.

Comment: Awesome, running only `latex` did the trick! Of course, just copying the file first would have worked too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `latex` supports reading from standard input then you can do it that way.

Possibly just `latex` or maybe `latex -` or possibly `latex /dev/stdin` to fake it as a local file.

If that doesn't work then you need to transfer the file over first.

Answer (score 2):

```
scp report.tex latex@192.168.2.8:/home/Jeanluca/build
ssh latex@192.168.2.8 "cd build && ./linux_build" < report.tex
scp latex@192.168.2.8:build/report.pdf
```

Try sending your tex file over first.  To the full path for the build directory.

Answer (score 2):

I know your frustration. It grew so big that I put together a small script which *efficiently* runs LaTeX on a remote server.

It prestarts LaTeX on the remote end with the preamble of the previous run such that LaTeX has already loaded the required packages and is ready to go when changed contents arrives, and starts streaming the resulting PDF file immediately (before LaTeX has finished writing to it). Also dependencies (images, included source files etc.) are transparently handled.

Maybe you too find it useful: https://github.com/iblech/sshlatex

No installation is necessary. Execution is simple:

> $ sshlatex ssh.example.org foo.tex

Comment: Very nice. You mention that one of the dependencies is `LaTeX`, but I think that is not very clear. Could you maybe add some extra documentation there on how to install LaTex (or a download link) and maybe a list of all the tool-names used by this script ? Also interesting is to add a DockerFile (I'll create a PR for this if I have time!!)

Comment: @Jeanluca: Thanks for your feedback! I'll amend the documentation. Yes, LaTeX needs to be installed on the remote end. Depending on your Linux distribution, a simple `apt-get install texlive` suffices for this. With the exception of inotify-tools, sshlatex uses absolutely no tools which go beyond a basic Linux installation. I'll gladly accept pull requests! Sadly, I don't have any experience with Docker myself.